# Undefined symbol during dlopen

Tags: c++, linux

Trying to load shared lib:

```
handle = dlopen( "libaaa.so.2.5", RTLD_NOW );
  if ( !handle )
    {
      printf("Failed to open aaa lib: %s\n", dlerror());
      return 1;
    }
```

When I run ./myBinary got error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE
```

What this symbol means? How to fix this problem?

Comment: This symbol means "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info"

Comment: What does this men? Will it help to fix problem?

Comment: You asked question "What this symbol means?" I answered it. Google for undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE" there is plenty of information.

Answer (score 4):

The executable probably requires `-lstdc++`. If linked with `gcc`, link with `g++` instead, it links in the C++ standard library for you.

Answer (score 0):

Run (on your Linux or Unix system, using GCC or Clang as their C++ compiler) the `c++filt _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE` command to decode the [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). It tells

```
 vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info
```

So you should link your executable binary (or perhaps your `libaaa.so.2.5` shared library) with the standard C++ library (as suggested by [Maxim Egorushkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47893222/841108)).